# Can I use YouTube animated gif previews on my own site?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have been able to pull YouTube image previews on my own site using their widely known image URLs like this:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/{VIDEO-URL}/0.jpg
```

Is there something similar for the new animated gifs found on the Youtube.com website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not supported yet. You can make a [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&id=3y4BOzxP8Mw&fields=*&_h=10&) request and you can see that there's no gif there only jpgs.

This is also confirmed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47084113/get-youtube-animated-thumbnail).